# Phonegap is unable to install cordova plugins: The platform "browser" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, phonegap-cli, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm not able to install new plugins in Phonegap with the command: $ phonegap plugin add **.

For example, when I run **$ phonegap plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic**, the following error occurs:

```
Installing "cordova.plugins.diagnostic" for browser  


Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module '/Users/george/Documents/phonegap/TryPushNotifications/platforms/browser/cordova/Api.js'  


Failed to install 'cordova.plugins.diagnostic': Error: Unhandled "error" event. (The platform "browser" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. browser not supported.)  
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:19)  
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-common/src/events.js:71:17)  
    at Object.getPlatformApiFunction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js:500:20)  
    at Object.getPlatformApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:55:25)  
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:593:29)  
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:357:28  
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)  
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)  
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)  
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49  


Error: Unhandled "error" event. (The platform "browser" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. browser not supported.)
```

It seems like Phonegap didn't add a valid browser file, but I also try to create a new project with the phonegap command (which automatically creates a new push notifications project and same result).

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you running (`phonegap -v`)? And is that the same version of PhoneGap that you created your project with?